# Power supply and variable speed adjustment

Tags: power-supply

I have a DC makermotor model PN01007-38, rated voltage: 13.5 VDC. I would like to attach it to an AC to DC power supply. What specifications do I need on the DC side? I would also like to regulate its speed. What specifications do I need to pay attention to?

I do not have a data sheet. On the motor voltage is 12 VDC,speed is 50 RPM and Nominal current is 6 amps.

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link to the motor.

Comment: (Geared, "obviously". 60 W mechanical, nominally.)

Comment: `[I'd] like to regulate its speed` *regulate* reads *closed loop* to some. How to you want to *set* required speed - linear position of a slider? With a control voltage? Some "digital" value? Angular position of some knob? PWM?

Comment: Knob set it and leave it .

Answer (score 0):

You need a DC motor controller (aka, a brushed "ESC" - [Electronic Speed Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control)) between the power supply and the DC motor.

Comment: to my knowledge, most ESCs are for brushless motors, which is not the motor type that KingRPetty has.

Comment: A quick [check on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/esc/s?k=esc) shows that the term ESC is used for either brushed or brushless motors and it's about 50 % of each type. The ads specify which one.